# Tags muito abrangentes quando fora de um outro contexto (outra tag)

Tags: debate, tags

A tag [`Services`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/services) parece muito abrangente, em especial quando usada sem uma outra tag, isso é aceitável?

Sabemos que de forma geral se refere a serviços do sistema operacional, seja qual for, porém usar o termo apenas em inglês me parece estranho.

Não seria melhor se mais detalhado como "Serviços do Sistema Operacional" ou "Serviços do SO"?

Comment: Boa pergunta, eu não sei...

Comment: O termo me parece ok, pode ter uma outra como sinônimo em pt. O problema é se ela estiver sendo usada para qualquer coisa que seja um serviço. Pior ainda se for assim: [tag:web] + [tag:services]. Criar um texto indicando o uso correto seria uma boa. Quem se habilita?